# font alignment for hebrew language in html

Tags: fonts, cufon, hebrew

I am designing some static HTML pages with hebrew language and have applied some external fonts using `@font-face` in the CSS, but this thing doesn't work properly.

I also tried applying `<html lang="he">` in the source but fonts are still not cross-browser compatible.

I have tried this this using cufon but no significant results appeared afterall.

Link for my static page is:

http://g-axon.com/minisite-heb/

Someone please give a proper solution for this Problem if you have any.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Looks OK to me - I see Hebrew just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to use google fonts so it will supports in every browsers

[google font](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/getting_started)